# How to echo selected record?

Tags: cakephp, echo

i'm still a beginner, and guess it's a simple CakePHP question...

all i want is to echo retrieved data from database (one row is selected).

i have next code:

```
$cover_page = $this->Publication->find('list', array('conditions' => array('Publication.id' => $id)));
```

now, how can i echo field title from selected database row?

tnx in adv!!!

Comment: Just in case you haven't tried it; try the cake console and bake: http://book.cakephp.org/view/113/Code-Generation-with-Bake

Comment: If you just want a single row, you should be using `read()`

http://api.cakephp.org/class/model#method-Modelread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/view/449/find):

`find('list', $params) returns an indexed array, useful for any use where you would want a list such as for populating input select boxes.`

It will give a result as below

```
Array
(
//[id] => 'displayValue',
[1] => 'displayValue1',
[2] => 'displayValue2',
[4] => 'displayValue4',
[5] => 'displayValue5',
[6] => 'displayValue6',
[3] => 'displayValue3',
```

)

Since in your code you've specified the `id` to make the result only one record
,you may not really need to use it, though you can access the title with `$cover_page[$id]` if you've set the right displayfield.A normal way to do your work would be

```
$cover_page = $this->Publication->find('first', array('conditions' => array('Publication.id' => $id)));
```

or

```
$cover_page = $this->Publication->findById($id);
```

Both of them can get the title by

```
$cover_page['Publication']['title']
```

Answer (score 0):

You access it like this (CakePHP creates an array of the database result):

```
echo $cover_page['Publication']['title'];
```

To get it into the view do:

```
$this->set('cover_page',$cover_page);
```

Comment: The reason for having to specify the index 'Publication' is that when you are fetching associated models, the others will appear under their respective indices.

Comment: well, that is a problem, i tryed that before, but i'm getting an error:

Notice (8): Undefined index:  Publication [APP\controllers\publications_controller.php, line 302]

Comment: `find('list')` doesn't give a model-name index.

Comment: @SpawnCxy: Woops - I hadn't noticed that.
@user198003 - use $this->Publication->read(null,$id); That will return the single record corresponding to that unique id. Variants of find may return an array of records (containing only one record). If you want one result from a unique id, read is the standard way.